# cocos2d sprite explosion

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ip

Hey, does somebody know, how i can let a sprite explode?
a code like `[[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"supermario.png"] runAction:[CCExplode action......]];`
would be great!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you want to handle something like is to first put the explosion frames in an Array, then you want to create a CCAnimation where you would specify the delay between frames and then you would say, [mySprite runAction: myAnim].